# XML file contents to text area and PHP: Remove character replacement

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file which I'm retrieving its data with this PHP function `file_get_contents()`.

My intention is to provide an editor for this XML file, so the XML contents string are loaded in a textarea, then edited (if needed), and saved with `file_put_contents()`

The string that PHP returns contains replacement characters (the �). How can I remove this or find a better solution to this?

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
```

and it's retrieved as this:

```
<�?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
```

Comment: It looks like XML actually in ISO-8859-1, can you save it in UTF-8 and check again?

Comment: Anton, just did it and it worked... Problem is that I have to use this file as Unicode and it's not generated by me... any PHP function to convert the returned string to Unicode?

Comment: The encoding of the original file is in UTF-16, actually...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with this function (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.iconv.php):

```
iconv("UTF-16", "UTF-8", $content);
```

Where `$content` is the string with the data return from my XML file.
Since the encoding was UTF-16, just translated that to UTF-8, and now it works fine.

Thank you.

** IMPORTANT **

Just remember to convert it back to the original encoding, when saving its contents:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', $content);
```

Otherwise you'll end up reading chinese in your application, next time you load it! :)